# What type of food (herb, root) helps with sleep?

Tags: sleep, supplement, home-remedies, sleep-aids, herbs

Right now it's 3am local time.

Ideally I'd like to follow a protocol that would put me into sleep.

I've just had a juicy pear - it contains sugar that gives energy etc... From that standpoint it wasn't a great choice if I want go to sleep.

What are the **foods, herbs, roots** that are known for sleep-inducing properties?

Comment: for me a cup of warm (but, not hot!) lemongrass tea before bedtime, salad made with valerian and lavender essential oil from dottera helped. These are all safe, natural and also effective in the long term.

Comment: What I presume would be really effective will be taking lemon balm as an herb before bed, but as for food, it would be those containing tomatoes; you could also take bananas or rice if available. http://naturalsociety.com/8-foods-naturally-increase-melatonin-sleep/

Answer (score 6):

As an insomniac, I've looked into this myself, and found the following to be natural sleep-inducing foods (in no particular order):

- **Cherries** -- The tarter, the better. They have melatonin!! And they are great for desert.
- **Chamomile Tea** -- apparently it contains the chemical glycine, which helps relax muscles and nerves.
- **Honey** -- the natural sugar of honey helps the insulin levels to raise quickly so the tryptophan (the chemical in Turkey that makes people sleepy after a Thanksgiving meal) can enter the brain easier and help you fall asleep! Plus... it goes well with the Chammomile Tea!
- **Almonds** -- have lots of magnesium in it, and magnesium contributes to quality sleep. Also, try warm almond milk...
- **Walnut**s -- Like cherries, walnuts, also are chalk full of melatonin.
- **Oatmeal** -- Oats also have melatonin in them, but it also has B-6 in it which makes you relax as well. 2 components!

Here's a few websites:

16 foods that help you sleep: http://www.rd.com/health/beauty/foods-that-help-you-sleep/

9 foods that help you sleep better: http://www.prevention.com/food/foods-better-sleep

10 Foods that Make you Sleepy & 10 Foods that Keep you up: http://www.goodhousekeeping.com/health/diet-nutrition/g796/sleep-inducing-foods/?slide=6

**Unlike Prince, I have not found tomatoes good for sleep. I finds tomatoes or tomato based foods to be too acidic for bed time and it gives me acid-reflux. But I guess it all depends on you and your body!

Good Night!